# Passing a function to Powershell's (replace) function

Tags: powershell, replace

I want to pass a function call(which returns a string) as a replacement string to Powershell's replace function such that each match found is replaced with a different string.

Something like -

```
$global_counter = 0
Function callback()
{
    $global_counter += 1   
    return "string" + $global_counter
}

$mystring -replace "match", callback()
```

Python allows this through 're' module's 'sub' function which accepts a callback function as input. Looking for something similar

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx). In PowerShell a script block can be used as `MatchEvaluator`. Inside this script block `$args[0]` is the current match.

```
$global_counter = 0
$callback = {
    $global_counter += 1
    "string-$($args[0])-" + $global_counter
}

$re = [regex]"match"
$re.Replace('zzz match match xxx', $callback)
```

Output:

```
zzz string-match-1 string-match-2 xxx
```

Answer (score 10):

PowerShell does not (yet?) have support for passing a script block to the `-replace` operator. The only option here is to use `[Regex]::Replace` directly:

```
[Regex]::Replace($mystring, 'match', {callback})
```

Answer (score 0):

Many moons later, let me complement the **existing, helpful answers - which continue to work *in principle*** (see below) - with a **simpler *PowerShell (Core) 7* solution**:

Thanks to a contribution by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), [*PowerShell (Core) 7*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the cross-platform successor to the legacy, Windows-only *Windows PowerShell* (whose latest an *last* version is 5.1):

- now *does* support passing passing a *callback* as the substitution operand of the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator, ...
- ... namely in the form of a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), inside of which the [match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) at hand can be referred to via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_); `$_.Value` therefore refers to the matched *text*.

Therefore:

```bash
# PowerShell 7 only
$i = 0
'zzz match match xxx' -replace 'match', { 'string-{0}-{1}' -f $_.Value, ++$i }
```

Output:

```bash
zzz string-match-1 string-match-2 xxx
```

- Note the use of `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), to synthesize the substitution string that is output by the script block.
- Since the substitution script block runs *directly in the caller's [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes)*, you can apply `++`, the [increment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators#the-increment-and-decrement-operators), directly to the caller's `$i` variable.

---

The backward-compatible ***Windows PowerShell*-compatible solution** that is the equivalent of the above is the following, using [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace):

```bash
# Works in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7.
$i = 0
[regex]::Replace(
  'zzz match match xxx', 
  'match', 
  { param($m) 'string-{0}-{1}' -f $m.Value, ++(Get-Variable -Scope 1 -Name i).Value }
)
```

- The script block (`{ ... }`) that is passed acts as the [MatchEvaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator) delegate, to which the [match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) at hand is passed *as an argument*, which `param($m)` inside the script block formally declares.
- Unlike with `-replace` in PowerShell 7, the script block runs in a *child* scope of the caller, requiring extra effort to update a variable in the *caller*'s scope:

  - [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) is used with `-Scope 1` to refer to the *parent* scope's `$i` variable, whose `.Value` property can then be incremented with `++`.

    - For brevity, you can omit `-Scope 1`, and an even shorter - albeit obscure - alternative is to use `++([ref] $i).Value` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76819688/45375) for background information.