# PowerShell Replace number in string

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

I'm not such a `regex` expert and frankly I'm trying to avoid it whenever I can.

I would like to create a new `$String` where the number within the string is updated with `+1`. This number can be one or two digits and will always be between 2 brackets.

**From:**

```
$String = "\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[1] - 2014-07-29.log"
```

**To:**

```
$String = "\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[2] - 2014-07-29.log"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Escape brackets in regex (they're meaningful, not literal): `\[\d+\]`. If you're sure number can have only one or two digits then you may also make it explicit: `\[\d[\d]\]` or `\[\d\d?\]`

Comment: Thank you Adriano :) This seems to work partially already `$String -replace "\[\d+\]",'[bla]'` How can I update the number now within the brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid the regex:

```
$String = "\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[1] - 2014-07-29.log"
$parts = $string.Split('[]')
$Newstring = '{0}[{1}]{2}' -f $parts[0],(1 + $parts[1]),$parts[2]
$Newstring
\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[2] - 2014-07-29.log
```

Comment: +1 - Also important to note that order in the addition here matters , so do `1 +` not `...+ 1`. The latter will concatenate a string.

Comment: Thanks mjoninor, that is indeed a good way of doing and I was indeed wondering why the `1+` was before the string. I've updated the question to better reflect my problem. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question since checking if a file exists is different from incrementing a number in a file name.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the [`Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) method of the `Regex` class with a scriptblock (code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163281/1630171) by Roman Kuzmin):

```
$callback = {
  $v = [int]$args[0].Groups[1].Value
  $args[0] -replace $v,++$v
}

$filename = "\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[1] - 2014-07-29.log"

$re = [Regex]"\[(\d+)\]"
$re.Replace($filename, $callback)
```

Existing files could be handled like this:

```
...
$re = [Regex]"\[(\d+)\]"
while (Test-Path -LiteralPath $filename) {
  $filename = $re.Replace($filename, $callback)
}
```

Note that you **must** use `Test-Path` with the parameter `-LiteralPath` here, because your filename contains square brackets, which would otherwise be interpreted as [wildcard characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

With regex:

```
$s = "\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[1] - 2014-07-29.log"
$s -replace "(?<=\[)(\d+)","bla"
```

Result:

```
\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[bla] - 2014-07-29.log
```

So you can do something like this:

```
$s = "\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[1] - 2014-07-29.log"
$s -match "(?<=\[)(\d+)" | Out-Null  ## find regex matches
$newNumber = [int]$matches[0] + 1
$s -replace "(?<=\[)(\d+)",$newNumber
```

Result:

```
\\Server\c$\share_1\share2_\Taget2[2] - 2014-07-29.log
```

Comment: Thank you Raf, this would work. But how can you check afterwards, on a second run of the script, if that file name is already in use? It's difficult to feed the right `$Path` to `Test-Path` so it creates the new file name.

Comment: Dito to what @Entbark said, ask another question as the 2 are quite different.