# Powershell rename-item, replace old name using functions

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a list of files:

```
PS S:\temp> dir


    Directory: S:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00001_asdfasdfsa df.txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00002_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (3).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00003_asdfasdfsa df - Copy.txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00004_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (6).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00005_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (5).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00006_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (4).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00007_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (2).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 700006_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (4) - Copy.txt


PS S:\temp>
```

I want to renamem those that start with five numbers and an underline. The new name will add a number I specified to the leading numbers of those file names. For example, if I add 10, the new names would be:

```
PS S:\temp> dir


    Directory: S:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00011_asdfasdfsa df.txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00012_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (3).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00013_asdfasdfsa df - Copy.txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00014_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (6).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00015_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (5).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00016_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (4).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 00017_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (2).txt
-a---         3/28/2016   2:07 AM          0 700006_asdfasdfsa df - Copy (4) - Copy.txt


PS S:\temp>
```

Now my PowerShell code is:

```
dir * | ?{$_.name -match '^\d{5}_.+'} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '^(\d{5})(_.+)', ((([convert]::ToInt32('$1', 10) + 12).ToString("00000")) + '$2')} -whatif
```

I can't find any errors in my code. But when I run it, I got the following error message:

```
Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find any recognizable digits."
At line:1 char:62
+ dir * | ?{$_.name -match '^\d{5}_.+'} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace ' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (S:\temp\00001_asdfasdfsa df.txt:PSObject) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentInvocationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

My question is, where I am wrong? Is it because I should not use functions in the replacement part of the `replace` operator? If so, how to write complex logic in `-newname{}`? Thanks.

Comment: The reason your replace did not work is because of how -replace works. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163061/passing-a-function-to-powershells-replace-function. Basically '$1' literally means  the string "$1" and the regex engine does not get its hands on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `-replace` and massage the data at the time of the substitution. Your replacement was failing as the string literal `$1` cannot be converted to integer. As discussed in a similar question: [Passing a function to Powershell's (replace) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163061/passing-a-function-to-powershells-replace-function) you can use a scriptblock and the .nNet regex static method `Replace`.

```
$replaceBlock = {
    # Groups 0 contains the whole match. 1 is the first group... and so on.
    ([convert]::ToInt32($args[0].Groups[1],10) + 12).ToString("00000") + $args[0].Groups[2]
}

Get-ChildItem | Where-Object{$_.name -match '^\d{5}_.+'} | Rename-Item -NewName {
    [Regex]::Replace($_.name, '^(\d{5})(_.+)', $replaceBlock)
} -whatif
```

You can use the script block inline but getting it out makes for a little cleaner code. However I would likely use `-match` and the returned `$matches` object to do the same thing.

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object{$_.name -match '^(\d{5})(_.+)'} | Rename-Item -NewName {
    ([int]$Matches[1] + 12).ToString("00000") + $Matches[2]
} -whatif
```

Note that I updated the `where-object` to have capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I got an answer.

```
dir * | ?{$_.name -match '^\d{5}_.+'} | Rename-Item -NewName {(([convert]::toint32($_.name.substring(0, 5), 10) + 12).ToString("00000")) + $_.name.substring(5)} -whatif
```

Just found that I can use any code in the `-newname{}` block. But I still don't understand why my `-replace` way did not work.