# Regex on Powershell script: Replace till end of line

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have some config files structured like:

> PATH_KEY=C:\\dir\\project
>
> foo=bar

I want to write a small script that replaces a certain key with current folder.
So basically I'm trying to replace "PATH_KEY=..." with "PATH_KEY=$PSScriptRoot"

My code so far:

```
$cfgs = Get-Childitem $PSScriptRoot -Filter *name*.cfg

foreach ($cfg in $cfgs) 
{
  (  Get-Content $cfg) -replace 'PATH_KEY=.*?\n','PATH_KEY=$PSScriptRoot' | Set-Content $cfg
}
```

But the regular expression to take everything till end of line is not working.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *is not working* how? Why not use a mere `'(?m)^PATH_KEY=.*'` or even `'PATH_KEY=.*'`?

Comment: BTW, the replacement should be `PATH_KEY=$$PSScriptRoot`

Comment: thanks it worked. only thing now is that $PSScriptRoot is not using double backslash...

Comment: What do you mean by a double backslash? There is no backslash in `$PSScriptRoot`.

Comment: echo $PSScriptRoot -> C:\something
echo $PSScriptRoot.replace('\','\\') -> C:\\something

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to expand `$PSScriptRoot` variable inside a replacement string? It is not correct. You need to [provide a callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163061/passing-a-function-to-powershells-replace-function).

Comment: Just in case: `[regex]::Replace($str,'PATH_KEY=.*',{param($match) "PATH_KEY=$($PSScriptRoot.replace("\","\\"))"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
'(?m)^PATH_KEY=.*'
```

or even

```
'PATH_KEY=.*'
```

Note that `$` in the replacement should be doubled to denote a single `$`, but it is not a problem unless there is a digit after it.

See the demo:

[image]