# How do I generate Unique Guids for each Match

Tags: regex, powershell, guid

I'm trying to write a script that generates new GUIDs when finding a match. My issue is that I keep getting the same GUID generated for all matches.
How do I do this without generating the same GUID for all matches?

```
$testString = @"
    [assembly: Guid Should Replace]
    [assembly: Guid Should Replace]    
    [assembly: Guid Should Replace]
"@
    #expected output
    #[assembly: "unique guid"]

    
    function ReplaceWithNewGuid {
        param($content)
        $retval = ($content -ireplace '(?m)(\[assembly: Guid.*$)+', "[assembly: Guid(`"$([guid]::NewGuid())`"]`)")
        return $retval
    }
    
    ReplaceWithNewGuid($testString)
```

Example of actual output:

[assembly: Guid("29e784aa-ba4a-4a45-85b8-d6b52916b539"])

[assembly: Guid("29e784aa-ba4a-4a45-85b8-d6b52916b539"])

[assembly: Guid("29e784aa-ba4a-4a45-85b8-d6b52916b539"])

## Update

The answer from @Mathias R. Jessen helped me get what I needed. I was thinking I could do this in powershell without using the .net framework libs but, this works as expected.

```
function ReplaceWithNewGuid {
    param($content)
    $retval = [regex]::Replace($testString, '(?m)(\[assembly: Guid.*$)+', {param($m) return "[assembly: Guid(`""+ (New-Guid).Guid + "`")]"}, 'IgnoreCase')
    return $retval
}
```

Comment: [guid]::NewGuid() should always generate a unique value... that's the full script?

Comment: String interpolation happens before your command runs. So you generate the GUID to replace with once and then all the replaces happen. I think having each value be unique is going to be a lot more complex.

Comment: Sorry, but which `[assembly: Guid...]`  should be replaced?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the ones that say "Guid Should Replace"

Comment: @AustinFrench yep, it is

Comment: @Terrance Does that mean that only those should be replaced that are at the start/end of the line? Please provide an expected output.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I'd go with a string builder, split the full string, check each word for a match by guid, and then append the old or new guid to the string builder...

Comment: I'm asking about getting a unique string output per iteration using -replace vs the other question which is asking about rolling their own replacement function. Just because the two have similar topics and similar answers does not make this a duplicate. Just because the answer is 1 in the expression 3-2 and 30-29 does not make the question the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475(v=vs.110).aspx) directly, allows you to pass a scriptblock in place of the MatchEvaluator delegate parameter:

```
$testString = @"
[assembly: Guid Should Replace]
[assembly: Guid Should Replace]    
[assembly: Guid Should Replace]
"@

[regex]::Replace($testString, 'Guid Should Replace', {param($m) return (New-Guid).Guid}, 'IgnoreCase')
```

You should see that it returns 3 distinct identifiers

Comment: Yeah, the only problem was with the regex for the original input. After the edit, it is now a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163061/passing-a-function-to-powershells-replace-function

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried this with my existing regex and it works as expected. It's not the regex but this is the best answer.

Comment: @Terrance Yes, it is, all the problem for you was how to use a callback inside Regex.Replace.

Answer (score -1):

```
(New-Guid).Guid
```

Presto, `Guid`s on demand.

And your function repaired:

```
function ReplaceWithNewGuid
{
    param($content)

    $retval = ForEach ($Line in ($content -split "`n"))
    {
        $Line -replace 'guid.*$',"Guid(`"$((New-Guid).Guid)`"]"
    }
    Return $retval
}
```

Comment: `[Guid]::NewGuid().Guid`. Version 3 not required.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I must have an updated version.  It's showing 3.1 for me.  I'll remove that from the post

Comment: The issue isn't the GUID generation. The issue is that it's that only one is generated for the entire replace operation, not one for every replace.

Comment: @BenH his problem is not looping through and creating a new guid for each match, then

Comment: The original question before the edit had multiple matches per line. This answer has the assumption that there is only one guid per line.

Comment: I didn't see it in that case.  I worked with the question that was visible @BenH

Comment: Note that `New-Guid` requires PSv5+ (which, regrettably, the docs don't tell you, but [a change has been requested](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1105)).