# Does there exists a PowerShell Escape function for Special Characters

Tags: powershell, escaping, special-characters

Does there exists a PowerShell Escape function to replace control characters (as e.g. a carriage return) with [Special *PowerShell* Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters)?
(Similar to the [`Regex.Escape(String) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) for escaping special *regex* characters)
Or is there a smarter way to do this than the self-answer?
<sub>(I am less concerned with the Unicode escape sequence: `` `u{x} ``)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [regular expression callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163281/1701026):

```
$Backtick = @{}
foreach ($Char in '0abefnrtv`'.ToCharArray()) {
    $Backtick[$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("``$Char")] = "``$Char"
}
$SpecialCharacters = '[' + (-Join $Backtick.get_Keys()) + ']'
function Escape($Text) {
    [regex]::Replace($Text, $SpecialCharacters, { param($Match) $Backtick[$Match.Value] })
}
```

```
Escape 'Test
123'

Test`n123
```

Answer (score 2):

Not as good as your code, but here's an alternative way:

```
function Escape([string]$Text) {
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Text)) { 
        $special = 0,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,27,96 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ }
        $escaped = '`0', '`a', '`b', '`t', '`n', '`v', '`f', '`r', '`e', '`'
        0..($special.Count -1) | ForEach-Object { $Text = $Text -replace $special[$_], $escaped[$_] }
    }
    $Text
}
```

```
Escape 'Test
123'

# --> Test`r`n123
```

Comment: It's conceptually clear, but likely to be quite slow.

Answer (score 2):

To offer a prepackaged solution based on the **`Debug-String` function**, available as [an MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1):

Assuming you have looked at the linked code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install it directly as follows:

```
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1/raw/Debug-String.ps1 | iex
```

The primary purpose of `Debug-String` is to visualize (hidden) control characters and spaces in strings (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45356836/45375)), but it also offers the **`-AsSourceCode`** and **`-SingleLine`** switches, which produce the desired single-line, control-characters-as-escape-sequences string representations (albeit *with* the enclosing `"` chars., but you can easily trim them with `.Trim('"')`.

Additionally, you may use **`-UnicodeEscapes`** in order to represent non-ASCII-range characters (e.g. `é`) by their Unicode escape sequences (e.g. `` `u{e9} ``), though note that such escapes are only recognized in *PowerShell (Core) v6+*.

```sh
Debug-String -AsSourceCode -SingleLine -UnicodeEscapes 'Tést`1
123'
```

The above yields (verbatim, *including* the `"` chars.), which can be copied and pasted into PowerShell code to expand to the original string:

```
"T`u{e9}st``1`n123"
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer by iRon, this version excludes 'e' if the powershell version is below 6. (It also puts the variables inside of the function because the code I'm using it for deals with the names of global variables returned by `Get-Variable`.)

```
function PSEscape($Text) {

    $Backtick = @{}
    foreach ($Char in ((@('','e')[$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 6])+'0abfnrtv`').ToCharArray()) {
        $Backtick[$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("``$Char")] = "``$Char"
    }
    $SpecialCharacters = '[' + (-Join $Backtick.get_Keys()) + ']'

    [regex]::Replace($Text, $SpecialCharacters, { param($Match) $Backtick[$Match.Value] })
}
```