# Show all special characters / escaped characters in powershell

Tags: powershell

In python if you place a string inside of a list it displays all special characters when you display the list.
[Python example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdHMh.png)

With code in powershell we start with:

```
$data = Get-Clipboard
```

How would I get $data to reveal all of the special characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get-Content and show control characters such as \`r - visualize control characters in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233342/get-content-and-show-control-characters-such-as-r-visualize-control-character) and/or [Does there exists a PowerShell Escape function for Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68132665/1701026)

Answer (score 3):

There is no builtin way that I know of to do what Python does, you would have to code it yourself.

`$Data | Format-Hex` will show you the character codes in the string, in hexadecimal. That's not easy to read, but it is enough to distinguish different whitespace characters:

```
PS C:\> $data = "A`r`nZ"
PS C:\> $data |Format-Hex


           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   41 0D 0A 5A                                      A..Z
```

0D is char 13, carriage return. 0A is char 10, linefeed.

If you wanted to code it, something like this:

```
PS C:\> $translated = foreach ($char in $data.GetEnumerator()) {
  switch ($char) {
    "`0" { '`0' }
    "`a" { '`a' }
    "`b" { '`b' }
    "`e" { '`e' }
    "`f" { '`f' }
    "`n" { '`n' }
    "`r" { '`r' }
    "`t" { '`t' }
    "`v" { '`v' }
    default { $char }
  }
}

PS C:\> -join $translated
A`r`nZ
```

Taking the codes from the [PowerShell tokenizer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/8d017d8a752cf960996c8c23c0f323a9cbe0f905/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/tokenizer.cs#L1469), what it will recognize inside double-quoted expandable strings as special characters, and turning them into single-quoted literal strings.

NB. not all of them can be turned back, I don't think. You could approach it differently [with a regex to match non-printable control codes, or Unicode categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564692/c-sharp-regex-to-remove-non-printable-characters-and-control-characters-in-a) and try to cover more cases that way.